# Remove first item from a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm studying the concepts of pointers in programming languages and I've come across this algorithm written in Java and I'm supposed to remove the first item of this list. I'm a beginner and I find myself struggling to resolve this.

```
public class mylist {

private static class mylist
{
    public int num;
    public mylist nextn;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    mylist start = null;
    mylist end = null;
    mylist aux;
    mylist before;
    int op, number, found;
    do{
        System.out.println("1- insert number in the beginning list");
        System.out.println("2- insert in the end of the list");
        System.out.println("3- query list");
        System.out.println("4- remove from list");  System.out.println("5- empty list");
        System.out.println("6- exit");
        System.out.print("choose: ");
        op = input.nextInt();
        if(op < 1||op>6)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid number");
        }
        if(op == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("type the number to be inserted in the beginning of the list");
            mylist newl = new mylist();
            newl.num = input.nextInt();
            if(start == null)
            {
                start = newl;
                end = newl;
                newl.nextn = null;
            }
            else
            {
                newl.nextn = start;
                start = newl;
            }
            System.out.println("number inserted");
        }
        if(op == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("type the number to be inserted in the end of the list");
            mylist newl = new mylist();
            newl.num = input.nextInt();
            if(start == null)
            {
                start = newl;
                end = newl;
                newl.nextn = null;
            }
            else
            {
                end.nextn = newl;
                end = newl;
                newl.nextn = null;
            }
            System.out.println("number inserted");
        }
        if(op == 3)
        {
            if(start == null)
            {
                System.out.println("list is empty");
            }
            else
            {  System.out.println("\nquerying the list\n");
                aux = start;
                while(aux!=null)
                {
                    System.out.print(aux.num+ " ");
                    aux = aux.nextn;

                }
            }
        }
        if(op == 4)
        {
            if(start == null)
            {
                System.out.println("list is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\ntype the number to be removed:\n");
                number = input.nextInt();
                aux = start;
                before = null;
                found = 0;

                while(aux!=null)
                {
                    if(aux.num == number)
                    {
                        found = found +1;
                        if(aux == start)
                        {
                            start = aux.nextn;
                            aux = start;
                        }
                        else if(aux == end)
                        {
                            before.nextn = null;
                            end = before;
                            aux = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            before.nextn =aux.nextn;
                            aux = aux.nextn;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        before = aux;
                        aux =aux.nextn;
                    }
                }
                if(found ==0)  {
                    System.out.append("number not found");
                }
                else if(found ==1)
                {
                    System.out.append("number removed once!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.append("number removed "+found+" times!");
                }
            }
        }
        if(op == 5)
        {
            if(start == null)
            {
                System.out.println("empty list");
            }
            else
            {
                start = null;
                System.out.println("emptied list");
            }
        }
    }while(op !=6);
}
```

}

Comment: That's what TAs are for. Schedule an appointment with them... you'll get more out of building a relationship with them than just getting this answered here. ;)

Comment: @samyi That assumes that the OP is attending a course at a school, and that the school has TAs, neither of which is given from the question.

Comment: SO is hotbed for students looking for an easy way out. userxxxxxx with reputation = 1.... pretty much guaranteed to be homework. Valid point though about the school possibly not having TAs. I was trying to teach him/her how to fish... instead of giving em fish. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just set `start` to the second element of the list:

```
start = start.nextn
```

Comment: you mean this?

if (start == null) { sout "list is empty"}
else { start = start.nextn; }

Comment: Pretty much.  I think you got this.